# A weighted geometric inequality

Tags: inequality, geometric-inequalities

$x,y,z$ are positive reals. for a triangle of side lengths $ a, b, c$ , and area $A$,
the following inequality holds:
$$(xa^2+yb^2+zc^2)^2\ge 16(xy+yz+zx)A^2$$
This is like a weighted Weitzenböck's inequality. I hope to get some tips to prove this question

Comment: What is $x,y,z$ here?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @the_fox I think  it's not exactly duplicate because my solution here is different than solutions in the linked topic.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg   The question is a duplicate. Is that not what matters?

Answer (score 0):

Let $a^2=q+r$, $b^2=p+r$ and $c^2=p+q$.

Thus, by C-S twice we obtain:
$$xa^2+yb^2+zc^2=x(q+r)+y(p+r)+z(p+q)=$$
$$=(x+y+z)(p+q+r)-xp-yq-zr=$$
$$=\sqrt{(x^2+y^2+z^2+2(xy+xz+yz))(p^2+q^2+r^2+2(pq+pr+qr))}-xp-yq-zr\geq$$
$$\geq\sqrt{(x^2+y^2+z^2)(p^2+q^2+r^2)}+2\sqrt{(xy+xz+yz)(pq+pr+qr)}-xp-yq-zr\geq$$
$$\geq2\sqrt{(xy+xz+yz)(pq+pr+qr)}=$$
$$=\sqrt{(xy+xz+yz)\sum_{cyc}(a^2+b^2-c^2)(a^2+c^2-b^2)}=$$
$$=\sqrt{(xy+xz+yz)\sum_{cyc}(2a^2b^2-a^4)}=4\sqrt{xy+xz+yz}A.$$
Done!